# c++ Type error for fixed-size array being passed to template requesting array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have a template function like the following:

```
template<typename T>    
T foo(byte* &buffer){
   ...
}
```

When I try to access it with a fixed-size array I get an error:

```
byte buffer[100] = {};
foo<int>(buffer);
```

However, when I create a new variable from buffer and pass that, no error:

```
byte buffer[100] = {};
auto b = buffer;
foo<int>(b);
```

What is the type of `buffer`? Is it not a `byte*`? Is there a way to cast it to a `byte*`? This only happens with a template function, otherwise it works as expected.

Comment: In both examples, `buffer` has type `char [100]`.     It is not possible to convert an array directly to a "reference to a pointer to an array of byte" which is what the first example attempts to do (and is not valid, since a reference to a pointer to an array of byte cannot be converted to a reference to a `byte *`).    In the second, `b` has type `byte *`, since the "array to pointer" conversion (which converts the name of an array into a pointer to its first element) occurs.  Since `b` is a `byte *`, and is not an rvalue, it can be passed by non-`const` reference to `foo()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the first case is because the array `buffer` **does not decay** because you have passed it be reference. That is you cannot bind a reference to a pointer to byte to an array of byte.

While in the second case `b` is a pointer which you can pass by reference.

**Solution 1**

One way to solve this is by removing the reference from the function parameter i.e., by the argument by value. So passing by value looks like:

```
template<typename T>    
T foo(byte* buffer){//note pass by value
   ...
}
```

Note in solution 1 you can modify the array from inside the function through the pointer. One disadvantage of solution 1 is that here you can also pointer other pointers(like pointer to int) so you have to take care by yourself that you don't try to access anything that is out of bound of the array. Other alternative would be to just pass the array by reference as you originally intended as shown in Solution 2.

**Solution 2** Pass the array by reference

```
template<typename T,  std::size_t N>
T foo(byte (&buffer)[N])//this time you're passing the actual array by reference and not the pointer to its first element
{
}
```

Now in solution 2 you have passed the array by reference and you can modify it directly inside the function template. Now `foo<int>(buffer);` will work.

Comment: I want to modify buffer within foo. Is that not possible?

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose you can do that. because you already passed your buffer by pointer.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose Since you have passed the pointer to the array, you can use that pointer to modify the array from inside the function.

Comment: Sorry, my brain is fried. I mean to say, I want to modify the pointer. But after reading everyone's helpful comments it looks like buffer is not a pointer but a different animal completely (array). Creating a new variable that is a pointer is the only option.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose I have also added an alternative solution(as solution 2) in my answer. In solution 2 the array is passed by reference as you originally wanted. Now you can change the array inside the function directly . Check it out.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose If you want to modify the pointer, you cannot pass an array.    You're making the mistake of believing an often-told lie that a pointer is an array (the reality is that an array can be used as if it is a pointer and vice versa in some contexts but not others)  An array is not actually a pointer and this is a case where that distinction matters.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with templates. Change `foo` to a non-template `void foo(byte* &buffer)` and you will see the same error.

`buffer` as declared in the function is of type **non-const reference to a pointer to `byte`**. In your second write-up, `buffer` is of type `byte[100]` with an l-value category. When assigned to `b`, decay happens and `b` is of type `byte*` with an l-value category. So `b` can be passed to `foo` without error. **Non-const reference can be bound to a non-const l-value.** Your first write-up does not work this way. Two simple fixes.

1. Change to `T foo(byte* buffer)`. This way, when passing `buffer` to `foo`, decay happens first, resulting in an r-value of type `byte*` (thinking about it as an unnamed temporary intermediate result) be passed to `foo` **by value** and that is okay.
2. Change to `T foo(byte* const buffer)`. Again, decay happens first, and **const reference can be bound to an r-value, whereas non-const reference cannot**.

If you prefer, may also declare `buffer` in `foo` to be of type non-const reference to `byte[100]`.